# simple if..else logic in python not working

Tags: python

Hello below is the simple logic to find if a person is eligible to vote or not.

Below python script will print as `"you can vote"` irrespective of the input.

```
age=raw_input("Enter age:")

if age < 18:
        print "cant vote"
elif age >= 18:
        print "you can vote"
```

**python script o/p:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# python test.py
Enter age:12
you can vote

[root@locahost ~]# python test.py
Enter age:23
you can vote
```

same logic works in below perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print"Enter age\n";
$age=<>;
chomp($age);

if($age < 18)
{
        print "cant vote\n";
}
elsif($age >=18)
{
        print "you can vote\n"
}
```

**perl scrit o/p:**

```
[root@locahost ~]# perl perl.pl
Enter age
12
cant vote

[root@locahost ~]# perl perl.pl
Enter age
18
you can vote
```

How does `if..else` will work in python

Comment: `age=int(raw_input("Enter age:"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as you see in the Code you are using raw_input, it will convert whatever you pass as argument to string. so basically your logic is

```
age=raw_input("Enter age:")


if age < 18: # i.e. '19' < 18 which is true
        print "cant vote"
elif age >= 18:
        print "you can vote"
```

i would suggest you to go with input or convert your age into integer.

```
age=int(raw_input("Enter age:"))
```

or

```
age=input("Enter age:")
```

Good luck buddy..!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the input age it to an Integer first, before doing comparisons, as seen below:

```
age=int(raw_input("Enter age:"))

if age < 18:
        print "cant vote"
elif age >= 18:
        print "you can vote"
```